# How can I turn my SWIFT functions into generics?

Tags: ios, swift

I am fairly new to Swift and have 4 different functions **that violate DRY** and work together to download two different images from two different URL's.

I am getting pre-signed URLS from S3...

Since I am downloading two images I have 2 functions for each image but this seems to violate the DON'T REPEAT YOURSELF principal and I'd like to make them generic so I can write less and more concise code.

below is my current code, I would appreciate that help!

THANK YOU

```
// THESE TWO FUNCS DO THE SAME THING WITH TWO DIFFERENT URLS
 func downloadIdImage() {
        guard let urlString = idUrl else {
            return
        }

        let url = URL(string: urlString)!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: 
getIdImageFromResponse(data:response:error:))
        task.resume()
    }
    
    func downloadSelfieImage() {
        guard let urlString = selfieUrl else {
            return
        }

        let url = URL(string: urlString)!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: 
getSelfieImageFromResponse(data:response:error:))
        task.resume()
    }
    
// THESE TWO FUNCS DO THE SAME THING WITH TWO RESPONSES....
    func getIdImageFromResponse(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) {
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }
        
        guard let data = data else {
            print("no image data found")
            return
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let loadedImage = UIImage(data: data) else {
                return
            }
            
            self.idImage = loadedImage
        }
    }
    
    func getSelfieImageFromResponse(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) {
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }
        
        guard let data = data else {
            print("no image data found")
            return
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let loadedImage = UIImage(data: data) else {
                return
            }
            
            self.selfieImage = loadedImage
        }
    }
```

Comment: you dont need generics just use a parameter. Just create a function downloadImage(url: String?) and for the second two you can make the function return an optional image

Comment: Let's not use generic (it's a specific term, with its meaning), but maybe instead factorization... I guess that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's factorize the completion first:

```
func getImageFromResponse(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> UIImage? {
    guard error == nil else {
        print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
        return nil
    }
    
    guard let data = data else {
        print("no image data found")
        return nil
    }
    
    let loadedImage = UIImage(data: data)
    return loadedImage
}
```

In use:

```
func downloadIdImage() {
    guard let urlString = idUrl else {
        return
    }

    let url = URL(string: urlString)!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { data, response, error in 
        guard let image = getImageFromResponse(data: data, response: response, error: error) else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async { 
            self.idImage = image
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}

func downloadSelfieImage() {
    guard let urlString = selfieUrl else {
        return
    }

    let url = URL(string: urlString)!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { data, response, error in 
        guard let image = getImageFromResponse(data: data, response: response, error: error) else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async { 
            self.selfieImage = image
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

That's the first step.

Now:

```
func download(image at: String?, completion: @escaping ((UIImage?) -> Void) {
    guard let urlString = at else { completion(nil); return }
    let url = URL(string: urlString)!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { data, response, error in 
        let image = getImageFromResponse(data: data, response: response, error: error)
        DispatchQueue.main.async { 
            completion(image)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

In use:

```
func downloadIdImage() {
    download(image at: idUrl, completion: { image in
        //Do you need to check if nil or not?
        self.idImage = image 
    })
}

func downloadSelfieImage() {
    download(image at: selfieUrl, completion: { image in
        //Do you need to check if nil or not?
        self.selfieImage = image 
    })
}
```

Now, let's avoid the force unwrap.

```
guard let urlString = at else { completion(nil); return }
let url = URL(string: urlString)!
```

Should be:

```
guard let urlString = at, let url = URL(string, urlString) else { completion(nil); return }
```